# What is this concrete structure we unearthed in our backyard?

Tags: identification, water, concrete

While working on a backyard project, we found a concrete structure that had been buried beneath a few feet of dirt.  It seems to be mostly constructed of concrete and some large rocks.  While digging it out, there were fragments of a clay pipe underneath it as well as some metal pipes.

Our home was built in 1921 in Portland, Oregon.

Any guesses as to what it may be?

[image]

Comment: Good interesting question & clear helpful illustration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like an old concrete-lined pond, perhaps one that also had a fountain (could that be the fountain in the center-top part of the photo?). The pipes would've been used to run the fountain, especially if the water source were uphill from the pond. Alternatively, the pipes could've been used to fill and "top up" the pond as needed.

Comment: Thanks Jurp!  Makes me wish I could have seen what it looked like when it was in use.  :)